# stubbing the protected function inherited from base class with sinon

Tags: javascript, typescript, unit-testing, sinon

I have a confusion on how to test protected method coming from super(inherited base class)

Here is what I have in the base class

```
export default class DataStoreBase {

protected _url: string;
protected _db: any;
protected _logger: LoggingService;
protected _name: string;
protected _type: string;

public constructor(logger: LoggingService, name: string, config: DatastoreConfig) {
    this._url = "";
    this._logger = logger;
    this._name = name;
    this._type = "";
    if (config.datastoreType === "cloudant") {
        const res = this.getCloudantClient(config.cloudant);
        this._url = res.endpoint;
        this._db = res.db;
        this._type += "Cloudant";
        this._logger.info({message: `${name} instance has been initialized.`});
    } else if (config.datastoreType === "couchdb") {
        const res = this.getCouchDBClient(config.couch);
        this._url = res.endpoint;
        this._db = res.db;
        this._type += "CouchDB";
        this._logger.info({message: `${name} instance has been initialized.`});
    } else {
        throw (new Error(CONFIG_INVALID_ERROR.message));
    }
}
```

and in another class I extend it:

```
export default class SearchesDatastore extends DataStoreBase {

 private bulkSize: number;
private designDocsPath: string;
 ....
public async getArchivedSearches() {
const _items = await this._db.find(q)
const items = _items.docs;
if (items.length <= 0) {
  this._logger.warn({ message: `No expired search queries found.` });
  return toBeDeleted;
}
bookmark = _items.bookmark;
for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
  toBeDeleted.push(items[i])
}
return toBeDeleted;
```

}

so as you see _db.find is coming from base class and it is protected variable
now I want to stub rhis._db.find
I try this

```
it("get archived queries", async () => {
  sandbox
    .stub(searchesDatastore, "_db")
    .resolves({ find: () => {return {docs: []}}  });
  // sinon.stub(searchesDatastore.prototype,<any>"_db").resolves({ find: () => {return {docs: []}}  });
  searchesDatastore.getArchivedSearches().catch((e:any) => {
    console.log(`eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee`)
    expect(e.message).to.be.deep.include("error");
  });
});
```

but stubbing does not happen
I am really confused and appreciate if anyone can help

Comment: What does 'protected' mean in JavaScript?

Comment: @ErnestoStifano it is actually typescript which allows us to add protected variables

Comment: Exactly. But, isn't the whole point of stubbing to intersect/change the value of something? And yes, 'protected variables' is not JavaScript. So there is nothing that keeps you from doing `searchesDatastore._db = yourStub;` before running the actual test, isn't it? And if TypeScript tries to complain, uninstall it. (Just kidding, tell him to ignore that)

Comment: @ErnestoStifano thanks a lot for answering and yeah a bit of improvement. it worked with searchesDatastore._db = { find: () => {return {docs: []}}  }; if I change protected _db: any; to public. However since the scope is protected I get Property '_db' is protected and only accessible within class 'DataStoreBase' and its subclasses.

Comment: You're welcome, but who is complaining? (Who is printing that message and throwing the error?)

Comment: @ErnestoStifano Actually typescript compiler does not compile it

Comment: I don't know the details of your setup, but every non JS code must be compiled before being run by a JS engine.